# Django ( 3.0.3 ) images inserted in my html projects

Tags: django, django-views

I’m working with Django and I have problems with images inserted in my html projects
I follow many suggestions but nothing works

In html I use:

```
{% load static %}
body{background: url("{% static 'images/barcelona_1.jpg' %}");
                              font-family: arial;}
<img src="{% static 'images/GreenStart.png' %}" height="130" width="400" alt="">
```

In urls.py I add:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [….
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

In settings.py I add:

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATICFILE_DIRS = [
   STATIC_DIR, 
]
```

Comment: what is your `STATIC_URL` ? can you view your static image in browser by going to ?supposing your static url is something like this `localhost:8000/static/images/GreenStart.png` ?

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/static/images/GreenStart.png
Raised by: django.views.static.serve

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'